# in ASP.NET MVC serve js html and css files from directory outside project directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Web API project, as well as a Single Page Application.  The single page application will be hitting end points from my web api project but will consist entirely of static html, js, and css files.  I want to keep my web api code in one repository, and my single page app code in a different repository, but only use a single site in IIS to serve the files as well as host the Web API.
SO, how can i configure asp.net mvc 5 to serve the static files from a directory outside of the project directory?  For example, let's say my Web API project is in:

> C:/Development/WebAPI

By default, IIS and ASP.NET MVC will look for all html, js, and css files starting from the root of my project which is C:/Development/WebAPI
However, my single page app code is in:

> C:/Development/SPA

So how can I configure things so that C:/Development/SPA is where the app looks when it receives requests for html, js, or css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to create a virtual directory in IIS named "SPA" that pointed to: C:/Development/SPA.  If you don't know how to do that, simply right-click on the website inside IIS, and select "Add Virtual Directory".

Answer (score 0):

you just need to have references to C:/Development/WebAPI and C:/Development/SPA from within your asp.net mv5 project.

Typically /api within you mv5 project will point to:

```
C:/Development/WebAPI
```

containing your webAPI cs controller files, and /SPA for example to point to:

```
C:/Development/SPA
```

containing your SPA html and assets / public folder.

This will work if your mvc5 project is just a container for WebAPI, because you have no need for mvc5 controllers.

Comment: how do you add references to a folder that is in a different place on your hard drive than the project?

Comment: 1. drag and drop or                                                  2. add folder in project and cut and paste files across using windows explorer and then select the "show all files" icon in the heading of Solution Explorer to see the "not included" folders/files. Then finally right click on folder/files to include into project